# nginx rewrite rule for strip numbers from final

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

Can someone help me with this issue on nginx or using .htaccess?

I want to redirect an url like:

```
[http][www]domainName.tld/folderName/a-name-with-dashes-15-and-numbers-and-a-number-of-at-least-5-digits
```

Becomes

```
[http][www]domainName.tld/newFolderName/a-name-with-dashes-15-and-numbers
```

or

```
[http][www]domainName.tld/a-name-with-dashes-15-and-numbers
```

with www or without www.
a more real example (without domain):

```
/folderName/test-1-test-again-123456789
```

becomes

```
/newFolder/test-1-test-again
# or
/test-1-test-again
```

Thanks a lot

@Later Edit: Add Nginx Config from server block

```
    listen ip:80;

    server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;

    root   /var/www/domain.tld/web;


    if ($http_host = "www.domain.tld") {
        rewrite ^ $scheme://domain.tld$request_uri? permanent;
    }


    index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml;



    error_log /var/log/domain.tld/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/domain.tld/access.log combined;

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /stats {

        index index.html index.php;
        auth_basic "Members Only";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/clients/client/web/web/stats/.htpasswd_stats;
    }

    location ^~ /awstats-icon {
        alias /usr/share/awstats/icon;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files /c91e3e9dc234ca8eec5e7e5309e2fcca.htm @php;
    }

    location @php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/web24.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location ~* ^.+\.(css|png|ico|ttf|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires max;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control: public;
    }

    location ~* ^/wp-admin/.*.(html|htm|shtml|php)$ {
       client_max_body_size 30M;
    }

    location ~* ^/wp-content/uploads/.*.(html|htm|shtml|php)$ {
        types { }
        default_type text/plain;
    }

    location ~* ^/static/.*.(html|htm|shtml|php)$ {
        types { }
        default_type text/plain;
    }

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~* (wp-comments-posts|wp-login)\.php$ {
       if ($http_referer !~ ^(http://www.domain.tld) ) {
          return 405;
       }
    }
```

Comment: First of all, nginx doens't support `.htaccess`, so are you using nginx, or are you using apache?

Comment: I know that nginx don't support `.htaccess`. **I need for nginx**, but if i somebody can help for `.htaccess` is not a problem, because i will convert it. Thanks

Comment: are you looking for the apache answer or nginx, you tagged both

Comment: I know, that i have tagged both. I need the answer for nginx, but if someone can give me the answer for `.htaccess` is also ok, because i can convert the rule from `.htaccess` to nginx or vice versa and i will post it also here. I'm interested on a rule that can do the redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
location ~ '(.*)\-[0-9]{5,}$' {
  return 301 $scheme://$server_name$1;
}
```

This should strip all trailing numbers, if the numbers at the end of the url are more than 5 numbers

Comment: Sorry that i ask you, this should work just with copy+paste? or i need to change something else? (i ask, because, if i copy+paste in the config file, the nginx don't start). Thanks a lot.

Comment: run `sudo nginx -t`, and tell me the output

Comment: could you add your current nginx config to the question

Comment: `nginx -t` output: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "5,}$" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/100-domain.tld.vhost:55
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now! And, as i have said before, i will convert this to `.htaccess` and post it.